# Icons missing on cytoscape-panzoom plugin

Tags: cytoscape-web

I want to use the cytoscape-panzoom plugin distributed with Cytoscape.js. In my html page, I have included the according files from the cytoscape-web/plugins directory, as well as jquery and jquery-ui:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/jquery.cytoscapeweb-panzoom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.cytoscapeweb-panzoom.js"></script>
```

In the css file `jquery.cytoscapeweb-panzoom.css` I have modified the locations of the png files containing the ui-icons as advised in the comment (the png files are accessible, I can see them when I paste the link in the browser):

```
.ui-cytoscapeweb-panzoom-zoom-button .ui-icon {
    /*background-image: url("../images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png"); /* point to your copy of the img */
    background-image: url("http://cpdb.molgen.mpg.de/download/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
}

.ui-cytoscapeweb-panzoom-pan-button .ui-icon {
    /*background-image: url("../images/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png"); /* point to your copy of the img */
    background-image: url("http://cpdb.molgen.mpg.de/download/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png");
}

.ui-cytoscapeweb-panzoom-static .ui-cytoscapeweb-panzoom-zoom-button .ui-icon {
    /*background-image: url("../images/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png"); /* point to your copy of the img */
    background-image: url("http://cpdb.molgen.mpg.de/download/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png");
}
```

However, after the page loads, the panzoom controls (the circle, slider, etc.) are missing their icons, as can be seen in this screenshot (resource does not exist anymore). Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building from the master branch, you may have to redownload the stylesheet.  I think the selectors you have are out-of-date since the name change.  The class names wouldn't have `cytoscapeweb` in the name anymore.

Comment: Then you probably do have an issue accessing the images.  Are your images on a different domain?  Is your server set up properly to allow access to a different domain?  If it's not that, you've probably overridden the CSS elsewhere.  You've also got a white PNG in there, making things not visible.

Comment: The white color was a good point I hadn't thought about, but changing this does not fix the issue.  The images were on the same domain, now I even copied them to the same directory where the css is (and changed the according line to `background-image: url("ui-icons_000000_256x240.png");` in the css) - still nothing. [Here is the complete css](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c972uvdlb73w4gc/jquery.cytoscapeweb-panzoom.css), in case you would like to have a look:

Comment: The Web console of Firefox agrees that the image is found: `GET http://cpdb.molgen.mpg.de/TCPDB/javascript/jquery.cytoscapeweb-panzoom.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 11ms]`, `GET http://cpdb.molgen.mpg.de/TCPDB/javascript/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 6ms]`.

Comment: Ah, I just read in the "issues" section of the github project page that you will be refactoring the plugin, so I guess I will just wait for the new version. In any case, thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Please point me to your project URL.  It's easier for me to debug that way so I can help you out in the meanwhile.

Comment: Sure: [here it is](http://cpdb.molgen.mpg.de/CPDB/inducedmod). (click on "Example list" an then on "Proceed" at the bottom of the web page, then on "Find induced modules" at the bottom of the next page. Cheers!

Comment: The panzoom uses jQuery UI.  Without jQuery UI's JS *and* CSS, the control won't work.

Comment: Thanks Max, that was indeed the problem - I had forgotten the css of jQuery-ui. Cheers!